# JMockit - returnsFirstArg equivalent

Tags: mockito, powermock, jmockit

I have to mock a method using jmockit which returns the same arguments I passed. With Mockito, I used AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg:

```
PowerMockito.when(entityManager.merge((Request)Mockito.any())).then(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg());
```

How can I write this with jmockit?

```
new Expectations() {
        {
            entityManager.merge((Request) any);
            returns(????);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMockit doesn't have this feature out-of-the-box, but it can be implemented easily enough, with a reusable `Delegate` class:

```
class FirstArgument implements Delegate<Object> {
    Object delegate(Invocation inv) { return inv.getInvokedArguments()[0]; }
}

@Mocked EntityManager entityManager;

@Test
public void expectationRecordedToReturnAnArgument()
{
    new Expectations() {{
        entityManager.merge(any);
        result = new FirstArgument();
    }};

    // From the code under test:
    EntityClass entity = new EntityClass();
    EntityClass merged = entityManager.merge(entity);

    assertSame(entity, merged);
}
```